# Vim Eclipse colorscheme

Tags: vim, colors, color-scheme

I've installed Eclipse colorscheme but Vim doesn't look like the screenshots (see http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1802). My background is black with green/grey text. How do I make it look like it should? I do not use gVim but run Vim from the terminal.

Answer (score 2):

It looks to me like this colorscheme was mostly written for gvim.  There are color definitions for console vim however they are using the default color names which are very limited.  Try running gvim with this colorscheme and see if it is what you are expecting.

If the colorscheme works properly with gvim you should be able to use [CSApprox](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2390) to use it in the console version of vim.

Comment: The colorscheme works fine with GViM. It's understandable : from a terminal, most often you have only a few colors available while the GUI can use all of them. Also, ViM can't change the background of a terminal.

Comment: Both of those statements are sort of untrue.  Many terminals nowadays have 256 colors (which is plenty for a decent colorscheme) at their disposal, and vim can change the background of a terminal just fine with `ctermbg`.

Answer (score 0):

I rewrote the eclipse colorscheme for vim terminal. Copy the content below in a file (e.g., eclipse.vim) and save it in your `.vim/colors` directory.

```
set bg=light
hi clear
if exists("syntax_on")
    syntax reset
endif

let colors_name = "eclipse"

hi Normal               guifg=#121212 guibg=#ffffff                                             ctermfg=233   ctermbg=231
hi ErrorMsg     guifg=#ffffff guibg=#287eff gui=bold                ctermfg=115   ctermbg=236    cterm=bold
hi Visual       guifg=#8080ff guibg=fg      gui=reverse             ctermfg=69    ctermbg=fg     cterm=reverse
hi VisualNOS            guifg=#8080ff guibg=fg      gui=reverse,underline           ctermfg=lightblue ctermbg=fg cterm=reverse,underline
hi Todo         guifg=#ffffff guibg=#005FAF                     ctermfg=15    ctermbg=25     cterm=bold
hi Search       guifg=#90fff0 guibg=#2050d0                     ctermfg=white ctermbg=darkblue cterm=underline term=underline
hi IncSearch            guifg=#444444 guibg=#ffff00                     ctermfg=238   ctermbg=226

hi SpecialKey       guifg=#005FAF                               ctermfg=25
hi Directory        guifg=#005FAF                               ctermfg=25
hi Title        guifg=magenta gui=none ctermfg=magenta cterm=bold
hi WarningMsg       guifg=red           ctermfg=red
hi WildMenu         guifg=black guibg=yellow ctermfg=black ctermbg=yellow cterm=none term=none
hi ModeMsg          guifg=#22cce2       ctermfg=lightblue
hi MoreMsg          ctermfg=darkgreen   ctermfg=darkgreen
hi Question         guifg=green gui=none ctermfg=green cterm=none
hi NonText          guifg=#0030ff       ctermfg=darkblue

hi StatusLine   guifg=blue guibg=darkgray gui=none      ctermfg=blue ctermbg=gray  term=none term=none
hi StatusLineNC guifg=black guibg=darkgray gui=none     ctermfg=black ctermbg=gray term=none cterm=none
hi VertSplit    guifg=black guibg=darkgray gui=none     ctermfg=black ctermbg=gray term=none cterm=none

hi Folded   guifg=#808080 guibg=#000040         ctermfg=darkgrey ctermbg=black cterm=bold term=bold
hi FoldColumn   guifg=#808080 guibg=#000040         ctermfg=darkgrey ctermbg=black cterm=bold term=bold
hi LineNr   guifg=#a8a8a8 guibg=#121212         ctermfg=248      ctermbg=233

hi DiffAdd  guibg=gray                           ctermbg=gray  cterm=none  term=none
hi DiffChange   guibg=darkmagenta ctermbg=magenta cterm=none
hi DiffDelete   ctermfg=blue ctermbg=cyan gui=bold guifg=Blue guibg=DarkCyan
hi DiffText cterm=bold ctermbg=red gui=bold guibg=Red

hi Cursor   guifg=black guibg=yellow ctermfg=black ctermbg=yellow
hi lCursor  guifg=black guibg=white ctermfg=black ctermbg=white


hi Comment  guifg=#3F7F5F                                   ctermfg=28
hi Constant guifg=#0000C0                                   ctermfg=19                    cterm=none
hi Special  guifg=#0000C0                                   ctermfg=19                    cterm=none
hi Identifier   guifg=#7F9FBF  gui=bold                             ctermfg=110                   cterm=bold
hi Statement    guifg=#7F0055                           gui=bold                ctermfg=89                    cterm=bold
hi PreProc  guifg=#7F0055                           gui=bold                ctermfg=89                    cterm=bold
hi Type     guifg=#7F0055                           gui=bold                                ctermfg=89                    cterm=bold
hi Underlined   cterm=underline term=underline
hi Ignore   guifg=bg ctermfg=bg
```

I'm conscious that it's not complete. Let me know if there are problems.